# How to re-enable 640x480 resolution for special purpose display on Server 2008r2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, screen-resolution

The lowest resolution that Windows Server 2008r2 allows through the screen properties dialog is 800x600. I have a special secondary display that needs to run at 640x480.  This has previously been running on Windows Server 2000, which supports 640x480 just fine. I want to retire the Win 2000 system and move the application to the 2008r2 box.

Is there any way (registry etc) to re-enable the 640x480 resolution option on the secondary monitor?

The display does not support DDC and is identified as an unknown analog monitor.

Comment: 1. Your tag says Windows Server 2008 but your question states Windows Server 2008 R2. 2. In order to "re-enable" something it has to have been enabled in the first place. 3. I don't see a way to do this even using the Microsoft Standard VGA driver.

Comment: By "Re-enable" I mean re-enable a capability that was present in previous versions of Windows.  The hardware is of course capable, so I'm assuming there is a list of resolutions somewhere, and 640x480 was removed at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little experimentation with some code I had around from another project a while back that directly accesses the Windows API for displays (EnumDisplaySettings and ChangeDisplaySettingsEx)

It was pretty easy to adapt it to set a resolution on a specific display from the command line.
It works like a charm.   I think MS just removed the setting from the dialog, but not from the underlying API and/or driver.

If anyone else needs a Windows command line tool for setting display resolution, I have posted it on [my command line utilities page here](http://synthify.com/utilities/MyUtils.html#DisplayResSet).

```
Usage: DisplayResSet.exe /H -    This help
       DisplayResSet.exe with no parameters - list current display devices and supported modes
       DisplayResSet.exe /Dn /Xxxx /Yyyy - set resolution of device n to xxx by yyy pixels
       DisplayResSet.exe /Q - Quiet mode - suppress console output
```